# How can i make a LiveUSB of WIndows 8?

Tags: usb, windows, kubuntu, kde

buddies.
Yeah, i'm kinda noob in this so i need help... I need windows for the college an i have tried multiple ways to make a LiveUSB out of a ISO of WIndows 8 (32Bit) and nothing worked, so i need a guide through the process, i've got Kubuntu 32Bit  and the ISO of WIndows... pleas Help D:

Comment: You mean a live USB of Kubuntu from windows or a live USB of windows from kubuntu? The latter is not possible.

Comment: I think i'm kinda stuck, because i need a LiveUSB of Windows from Kubuntu...

Comment: Then you're permanently stuck. Windows doesn't support live modes at all. At best you can make the USB a bootable installer. That can be done using WinUSB.

Comment: for a step-by-step tutorial see [How to Run a Portable Version of Windows from a USB Drive](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-run-a-portable-version-of-windows-from-a-usb-dri-1565509124) but within Windows

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this is the right "ASK" for your question, but give the following a try, Sounds better than BartPE, (I have not tried it):

http://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/

Edit:
Oops, did not see the above comment concerning the Lifehacker post.